# Spring - Register an event listener programatically within an bean

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to register an existing spring bean to also be a listener to a custom spring event, programatically (i.e. within the java code via a method like addListener()?)

I already have a reference to the application context in the bean, and the custom event is being fired correctly elsewhere in the system.

If it is not possible, then how would I configure this already existing spring bean to also listen for a specific event?

This is the code in my context xml that allows my beans to be specified automatically via scanning...

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package"/>
```

And this is how the bean we have is currently defined...

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class EMIngEstateUI
{
...
}
```

We need this bean to be able to detect certain events.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Why  wouldn't you be able to implement the `ApplicationListener` interface?

Comment: I tried that, and that creates a new instance of this spring bean when the event is fired. What I need is for my bean (already instantiated and running much earlier) to react to the events, and it doesn't appear to do that (even when implementing the ApplicationListener interface).

Comment: Well your bean is prototype scoped so what would you expect. If that isn't what you want make it a singleton. Why is it prototype scoped anyway?

Comment: Sorry, Spring newbie so if I am doing anything strange I apologise. The Spring Bean is a Vaadin UI instance (recently integrated into a bigger Spring MVC architecture). It starts when the user selects our legacy app. It is set to "prototype" as I would ideally like the user to be able to start more than one instance (e.g. per browser tab), maintaining our legacy behaviour. I would have thought that as it is a Spring bean, then it must be able to listen to events on the Spring framework. Hence why I ask can I register it programatically....

Comment: When an event is fired `ApplicationListeners` are looked up from the `ApplicationContext` and hence each time a new instance of your prototype is created. After that no more events will be received so no that won't work. Spring doesn't control the prototype scoped beans hence you are basically on your own. You could create a register which keeps track of all your prototype scoped beans and delegates the events to them. Drawback is you need also to be aware of destruction callbacks (when do yu need to stop using an instance?).

Comment: Yeah, thanks! That was the fallback plan - maintain a list of my started beans against the session, and have a separate listener work on that list. Its not ideal though; I just wanted my prototype beans to register themselves as listeners, and be responsible for cleaning themselves down - nice & encapsulated. Seems like such a simple request, and I can't believe its not possible. They each have an ApplicationContext reference from which they can publish events, but they can't register to listen. ARGH :)

Comment: Well you could try using `applicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster().addApplicationListener(this)`; However you would also need to keep track of the destruction of your bean. Depending on the spring version YMMV...

Comment: Using Spring 4.1.6, and unfortunately a applicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster() method does not appear to exist. That was the kind of thing I was looking for though...

Comment: Cast to `ConfigurableApplicationContext` and do `((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).addApplicationListener(this)`. Or cast to an `AbstactApplicationContext` to get the `ApplicationEventMulticaster`.

Comment: Hi. Got it like this...

     Object o = applicationContext.getBean("applicationEventMulticaster");
     if (o != null)
     {
      ((ApplicationEventMulticaster)o).addApplicationListener(this);
     }

This appears to do the job nicely. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Greatly appreciated!

(Note: I'll use your solution as it is probably more stable than looking for  a specific bean name)

Comment: Instead of name you can always use the type `ApplicationEventMulticaster` instead of the name.